# How big xml file we can parse in iPhone application

Tags: iphone, xml

I will have xml file on server. It will store information of about 600 stores. information includes name, address, opening time , coordinates. So is it  ok to parse whole file into iphone then select nearest stores according to coordinates?

I am thinking about processing time and memory use

Please suggest

Comment: You should probably profile the memory and time yourself and check the results as its a very relative opinion.

Comment: But if it would be feasible then i will create my database accordingly and will create xml file. So before that i need to know the feasibility of idea itself.

Comment: As @Praveen has suggested try to use instruments to check on the CPU memory usage using instruments, however I recommend that you split your xml file into smaller chunks and then use "Pagination" to append more data. I am sure you are already aware of this 'Don't forget to test your code on iOS device using wi-fi and cellular network.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I would do this is write a web service and pass it the coordinates and download only those within a certain radius.  Always try to download as little data as possible to the iPhone (especially xml data)

Comment: Yes this was the other thought. But i dont know how to make web service doing this thing.

Comment: Thanks Praveen, I actually use this for a parking app I wrote and it works very well.

Comment: @Manjinder rails will allow you to write a very simple web service to do this.

Comment: @ennuikiller  Thanks for the advice. Ok i am trying to make webservice using rails. though i never made that. anyhow. so as u said u have also implemented this sort of app. So my webserver will take coordinates and query mysql database and it will return xml file of related stores. but how webserver know which are the nearest stores to given coordinates. Can you suggest me some guide or your experience. It would be great help and really appriciate

Comment: @Manjinder your database needs to contain the latitude and longitude and each store

Comment: Yes no problem with that. but how actually this calculation of retrieving nearest stores to given coordinates going to work. like say we have stores having coordinates . we have our mobile coordinats as well. how this comarison is going to happen. this is what i am wondering

Comment: The idea is to calculate a certain radius on the iPhone and then send the max and min  latitude and longitude to the web service and select stores with this min and max

Comment: Well i got your point and agree with that. thanks for showing me some way. I think Ruby Programming language is used to make web server. can you provide and guide or tutorial. i myself have looked into web. REally appreciate your thoughts.Cheers!

Comment: Mr @ennuikiller there is one very important point came into my mind. say about 1000 users request xml file from webserver at the same time? so can webserver generate 10000 xml files simultaneously?

Answer (score 1):

I just put this here 
http://quatermain.tumblr.com/post/93651539/aqxmlparser-big-memory-win

Comment: So you are suggesting me using AQXmlparser? i have used GData parser already for parsing other file in same applicaiton. can i use two parser with same application?

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution would be to group them into clusters that are somehow related, probably by location. You already have an XML on a server, so simply split them up into 3 groups of related stores of around 200, or preferably even smaller. I'm not entirely sure on why you would want to store 600 data points of that nature. I feel that if you filter/shrink on the server side you could be saving a lot of time/memory.

I have seen people storing 300-400 data points, though it is so dependent on how large your defined objects in your Core Database are, that it is probably best for you to just run some tests.